SRAM MTH 716/746 front/rear wheel hub service manual
I am looking for the service manual for the SRAM MTH 716/746 front/rear wheel hubs. SRAM seems to have removed them from their site. Anyone have a link?
Also, I've looked through YouTube and can't find any how-to videos for those components. Anyone have a link to one?

As far as I can tell, looking back at archived versions of the product page for the 700-series hubs, SRAM never posted a product-specific service manual for that part.  (The Internet Archive also has a partial view of their 2020 archived documents page that doesn't have it either, though it's possible its out of range of the indexed subpages.)
Instead they appear to assume that the parts catalogue (page 95) and the generic hub service manual should be enough to figure it out.
Obviously I can't verify that this is actually the case, but since this appears to be the state of available information as of 2020, it's about all the official information there seems to be.  Note that the MTH 300, MTH 500 and several other series' hubs also don't have model-specific service manuals.

Yeah, I also noticed they've dissapeared that information from their site and youtube. If anyone finds it, I'd love access.
